# How can you change the text when the bot processes slash command?

Tags: discord.py

perhaps from the title, the question is not very well aware that I wanted to ask, so sorry at once. So, I saw in some bots how they changed the text while processing the team. Here's what text I mean:

[image]

There, instead of "Sending сommand" was "Bot Thinking…". I don't know if I may confuse it with something else or in discord.py. Therefore, I am interested in whether there is such opportunity in discord.py. If this is, I will be glad to read more about it.

Comment: Pretty sure you cannot change the message. The `"{bot name} is thinking..."` will show up when you defer a message. Docs for defer: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html?highlight=defer#discord.InteractionResponse.defer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah it is really easy
that is only in slash commands and views...
you should type

```
await interaction.response.defer(thinking=True)
```

that is used mainly if there is a certain command will take time to process
and u should follow up to send a message

```
await interaction.followup.send("whatever")
```